# Combining prenex and disjunctive normal form

Tags: logic

Is every first order formula in L equivalent to a prenex formula with the matrix in disjunctive normal form over the non-logical constants of L?

If every quantifier free formula $\phi$ is equivalent to one in DNF, and sequences of quantifiers operate on the relation defined by $\phi$, that should be the case.

But then proving some property to hold for boolean combinations, and to be invariant with respect to the attaching of arbitrary sequences of quantifiers should be an alternative to induction on complexity.

Could someone confirm that this is right or give me a hint if I am missing something? Prenex with DNF matrix is conspicuously absent from the introductory books I've seen so far.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, every formula can be put in that form. However, to the best of my knowledge the task of

> proving some property . . . to be invariant with respect to the attaching of arbitrary sequences of quantifiers

requires induction on complexity, so I don't see that this provides an improvement in terms of showing that every formula has a desired property.

Comment: Why should it require induction on complexity? Sequences of quantifiers operate in specific ways on the sets defined by the matrix. If the property we are trying to prove can be inferred from the way the sequences operate (set-theoretically), that wouldn't require induction on complexity. Or what did you have in mind there?

Comment: @dizzieG I'm saying that those set-theoretic operations are best understood via induction. If you think otherwise, come up with an example where we don't need to go through induction! For example: can you show [quantifier elimination for Presburger arithmetic](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~tinelli/classes/295/Spring05/notes/quantifier-elim.pdf) without induction on complexity?

Comment: Thanks for your replies! OK perhaps there are no theoretically useful properties where this would be a *better* alternative to induction, I was just thinking of the general form of the sets resulting from the attachment of arbitrary sequences of quantifiers, in terms of the product structures on $Dom^n$. At least one can see and describe that directly without induction. But I'm sure you're right if you say that there is no advantage with respect to theoretically interesting properties. Explains why there's not much mention of prenex + DNF.